# Stack : Error in $.flags._: key "manual" not present

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I tried to add flag to `package.yaml` file

```
name:                sandbox
version:             0.1.0.0
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/sandbox#readme
license:             BSD3
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2017 Author name here
category:            Web
extra-source-files:
  - README.md

flags : 
    sandbox:
        defer-type-errors : true

dependencies:
  - base >= 4.7 && < 5

executables:
  sandbox:
    source-dirs:      src
    main:             Main.hs
    dependencies :    streaming
```

But I get following error :

> ....\sandbox\package.yaml: Error in $.flags.sandbox: key "manual" not present

Answer (score 1):

To tun on type-error deferral, teach Stack to compile with the flag inside **stack.yaml**, not package.yaml:

```
resolver: ...
packages: ['.']
ghc-options:
  sandbox: -fdefer-type-errors
extra-deps: []
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
```

The `flags` paragraph in package.yaml is meant to declare flags for *users of your package* to turn on or off. [See here for an example.](https://github.com/sol/hpack/blob/106a717d5f063ebb6c33e91e9c1e8a44d8baa167/test/Hpack/ConfigSpec.hs#L527) This is typically used for conditional compilation of optional features, like integration tests.

To adjust the flags GHC will use at compiletime, use `ghc-options` in stack.yaml. (Confusingly enough, there is also a `flags` in `stack.yaml`.)

Answer (score 0):

If this is the whole file, you must add (if you're using ghc-8.0.2) :

```
resolver: lts-8.3

flags:
  sandbox:
    defer-type-errors: true
```

Name is not necesary.

Comment: I think I have confused you a little bit. It is a package.yaml and my file looks a bit different.